Report Portal: API call to GET "cumulative" type of widget data
I have a "Cumulative trend chart" type of widget in one of my Dashboard and when I try to get the data of the widget via API using widget ID I get an error in the swagger API call.
{
"errorCode": 4001,
"message": "Incorrect Request. Unsupported widget type 'COMPONENT_HEALTH_CHECK'"
}
Can someone please let me know how to get data for "Cumulative trend chart" and "Component health check" type of widgets ?
